# where to find html code of a page

Tags: 7, theming

I am using Opigno (a LMS based on drupal) and I want to edit a page. I am looking for its HTML but when I open the code for the page this is what I found.

```
<?php print render($page['content']);
<?php print render($page['content_bottom']); ?>
```

I try to use print_r function in PHP and it displays an array of stuff.

How could I change the page if it is from php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Opigno but since it's based on Drupal, I'd say that you should change/edit the content of a page from its corresponding form once you're logged in.

If you want to edit the HTML, than you have to look for the page templates in your theme folders. This link may help you: https://www.drupal.org/search/site/theme%20template

Comment: Hi @scatteredbrainV I will try your comment ! Thanks!